# How can I tell what my partner's health is at?

Tags: hunted-the-demons-forge

I can easily see my health in the red at the top of the screen, and for the entire length of Chapter 1 I thought the blue was my partner's health. Turns out that's my mana (oops). So is there any way I can see my partner's health at the time, so I know if he's about to die or not? Would be good to know, so I don't go off doing risky things that could get me killed when my partner is about to die as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press select or back button then go to the abilities screen. You can switch characters by pressing X or square, and you can also see character info like life and mana.